# Google map Android api V2 activate compass and tilt mode

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I'm developing an Android application that displays a Google map. I want this map to be centered on the user position, and rotated to the user direction and tilt.
The behavior described can be seen in Google Maps application; When you click on the Location button once, it centers the map on your position. When clicked a second time, it achieves the described behavior.

How can I achieve this with the Google Maps API? Can I activate it programmatically? 
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the location as the center of the map, use:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
```

Then you should really take a look at `CameraPosition.Builder()` class from the docs. You will get all the answers there, but I'll show you an example of how it's being used:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
            target(location).
            tilt(degrees).
            zoom(zoom).
            bearing(bearing).
            build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: Isn't there any authomatic procedure to update the camera through the user position/direction? I need to program it myself?

Comment: Like I said, you will have to program that by yourself using the CameraPosition class.

Answer (score 0):

@Carnal's answer is helpful, but I think it doesn't quite answer your question.

Unfortunately, Google still hasn't implemented this feature to the Google Maps API, so you'll have to do it manually.

First you need to create a `CameraPosition` as @Carnal demonstrated.

Second, if you want the map to rotate the way a compass would, There are plenty of great tutorials on getting the compass values. Here's one: http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/android-compass-azimuth-calculating (Use the compass values for the `.bearing()` property on your `CameraPosition`)

Finally, call `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));` to move the map's "Camera"

Hope this helps!